# Detect if facebook Like button is viewable by the user or not

Tags: javascript, facebook

As you know, Facebook is filtered in many countries, and if we put a "Like" button in our page, they will see a "ACCESS DENIED" message form their internet provider instead of the Like button. so the question is, can I detect if Facebook is viewable by the user or not? so I just show the Like button if the users have access to Facebook and it's not filtered.

Thanks

Comment: Does the user really see an "ACCESS DENIED" message instead of just not seeing the button? What code do you use to show the button?

Comment: Yup, the thing is that I'm in a country which has filtered facebook, when I'm connecting to my website using VPN, I can see Like button and it's working fine and many people liked my page using the Like button, but when i'm not connected to VPN, then I see the "ACCESS DENIED" message from my internet provider. I'm using the facebook Like button generator: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test if the domain `www.facebook.com` is accessible by loading the `favicon.ico` and if so, show the iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php" id="fbfm" style="display:none">
</iframe>

<script>
var fbicon = new Image();
fbicon.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("fbfm").style.display = "";
};
fbicon.src = "http://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico?" + Math.random();
</script>
```

Comment: Smart solution, how I can show an error if it's not loaded? in your codes, this will show the iframe if it's loaded, I want to show an error if it's NOT loaded, for example: alert('cant connect to facebook');

Comment: +1 Very creative solution! :) @behz4d you could add an `onerror` handler, or check the dimensions of the image in the `onload` handler, as I believe this may sometimes be hit regardless of whether it really was successful, in which case the `width` and `height` will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could set a very small width and height on the like button iframe, just enough for the button itself, and hope that any "ACCESS DENIED" message has enough padding not be visible in the iframe's viewport! :)

The alternative might be to "ping" Facebook, as in make an AJAX request and see what the response is. **Hopefully** any blocked response from an ISP would contain an HTTP 403 status code, or something sensible, but if not you'd have to scrape the return HTML and try yourself to determine whether you're seeing Facebook or an error page, then decide whether to render the like button or not.

Comment: Not usable, because it loads another page instead of the Like button, in that page, there is also a javascript which redirect the user to another page, that's because I need to figure a way to not show the Like button otherwise the "ACCESS DENIED" message is not so harmful... about the ping, I just checked, I can ping it normally and there is no 403 status code

Comment: Damn, worth a shot. My next suggestion would be a server-side proxy, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Facebook javascript library at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

and use the FB.getLoginStatus(...) function to check and decide what you want your application to do.  If they have logged in or not (`connected` or `not_authorized`) then they are logged into facebook and you can show your like button.  If the status is `unknown` they haven't logged in yet but can see facebook.

If the facebook script does not load or return any value then facebook is probably blocked and you don't want to display your like button.

NOTE: You'll also need to create an app id with facebook to link your javascript to.

Comment: What would the status be if the user hadn't made any attempt to log in?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use a service like [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/) or [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/). There is a chance that they aren't blocked in your country (you can test it before you use it with and without a VPN) and they give you an advantage that your users can share your website with friends on other portals that are available to them.

It would certainly be interesting for other people to know whether or not those services are available in countries where Facebook is blocked as many of them can't test it themselves.

Comment: Not usable in my case, I'm using the "Like" button to unlock the content, I created an APP with facebook, I unlock the content while the users "Like" my page, using the mentioned services will ruin the whole thing... thanks anyway